# Decompose a positive number into the sum of 5 numbers in such a way that the sum of its inverse is maximal.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, extreme-value-theorem, extreme-value-analysis

I have to decompose a positive number into the sum of 5 numbers in such a way that the sum of its inverse is maximal.
I understand that is optimization, but I don't know how to do it with five variables.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "sum of its inverse"

Comment: Maybe you mean "sum of the reciprocals"?

Comment: And explain what you mean by "maximal".  Taking one or more of the numbers near $0$ gets you as large a sum as you like.

Comment: My idea, is that if I decompose the positive number N, in a+b+c+d+e=N, such that 1/a +1/b + 1/c +1/d +1/e = max

Comment: Are there any restrictions on these 5 numbers, otherwise the problem is currently ill posed and you can choose as small $a$ value of a as you want to reach as large a value as you want

Comment: Can $a, b, c, d, e$ be any real number? If so, please see lulu's comment.

Comment: For maximal,  I mean that you get the maximum number

Comment: Yes ,a,b,c,d,e can be any real number

Comment: And there are no restrictions

Comment: Then the problem makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be any positive number and let $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that
$$
N = a + b + c + d + e.
$$
Without any restrictions on what these $a,b,c,d,e$ are, then you can choose your numbers such that the sum of the reciprocals can take any value you want.

For the sake of example, let $b = N - a - 3$ and $c,d,e = 1$.
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d} + \frac{1}{e}\right) &= \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{N-a-3}\right) +3 \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} + \frac{1}{N - \epsilon - 3}\right) + 3 \\
&= + \infty
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your question as I understand it is:

> Given $\ \alpha > 0,\ $ what is the maximum, or more generally the
> supremum of
> $$S = \ \left\{ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}\ :a+b+c+d+e = \alpha\right\}\quad ? $$

There is no maximal number or supremum of $S.\ $ To see this, suppose by way of contradiction such a maximal number or supremum, $M\in\mathbb{R},$ of $S,$ exists.

We get to choose $\ a,b,c,d,e.\ $ Choose $\ a = \min\left\{\frac{1}{2M}, \frac{\alpha}{2}\right\}.\ $ Then $\ a < \alpha\ $ and $\ \frac{1}{a} > M.$

Then just choose $\ b=c=d=e=\frac{\alpha-a}{4}\ $ so that $\ a+b+c+d+e = \alpha\ $. Note also that $\ b,\ c,\ d,\ e\ $ are all $\ > 0,\ $ and therefore $\ \frac{1}{b},\ \frac{1}{c},\ \frac{1}{d},\ \frac{1}{e}\ $ are all $\ > 0,\ $ and so $\ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e} > \frac{1}{a} > M,\ $ contradicting the definition of $\ M,\ $ as desired.